# Is it possible to know which SQL WHERE clause didn't match?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

Can I get some specific error message when a WHERE/AND clause doesn't match?

For example something like this:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE    /* if date < current date -> ERROR 1 */
    AND name = 'John'         /* if name not equal 'John' -> ERROR 2*/
```

I am using a postgres database

Comment: Not as one statement. If you need that level of error raising all I'd suggest is that you put the first data set based on date into a temp table and check the row count. If zero raise error 1. If not zero, select from the temp table for name = john and do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` expressions tell you for each row if it's valid or not.

```
SELECT foo,
       case when date < CURRENT_DATE then 'ERROR 1' end,
       case when date <> 'John' then 'ERROR 2' end
FROM bar
```

Comment: So I have to do more statements? In this case it would select the whole data set, right?

Comment: Yes, this query will return every row. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT  foo,
    CASE WHEN date < current_date THEN 'ERROR 1' ELSE 'NO ERROR' END AS error_1,
    CASE WHEN name != 'John' THEN 'ERROR 2' ELSE 'NO ERROR' END AS error_2
FROM    bar;
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 0):

I might miss smth, but why everyone offers two columns?.. Why not

```
SELECT foo,
   case 
     when date < CURRENT_DATE then 'ERROR 1' 
     when date <> 'John' then 'ERROR 2'
     else 'OTHERS'
   end
FROM bar
```